# ShouldSerialize... mechanism seems to work no more

Tags: c#, serialization, deserialization

I have this piece of code:

```
[XmlIgnore]
public static Configuration Config;
[XmlElement("Configuration")]
public Configuration Configuration // property in myViewModel
{
    get { return Config; }
    set { Config = value; }
}

bool serializeConfig = true;

bool ShouldSerializeConfiguration()
{
    return serializeConfig;
}
public void ResetConfiguration()
{
    serializeConfig = true;
}
```

and a function where I use it:

```
private void SaveToClipboard()
{
    serializeConfig = false; // toggle no serialization
    try
    {
        XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(myViewModel)); // object that the Configuration is in

        using (StringWriter stream = new StringWriter())
        {                
            serializer.Serialize(stream, this);                
            Clipboard.SetText(stream.ToString());
        }
        serializeConfig = true; // toggle back
    }
    catch (InvalidOperationException e)
    {
        // etc.
    }            
}
```

I use serializeConfig to toggle serialization of the Configuration object.
I serialize in two places, one of which does not require Configuration.
But it does not work as advertised.

With [XmlIgnore] it skips Configuration as it should.

SaveToClipboard is a method of myViewModel, which is serialized.

Is this facility not supported anymore or what?
I use VS2017 latest update, on win10Pro.

Comment: why not use a bool parameter for your method and change the value? also is the save clip a method of the class you are  trying to serialize?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When used with `XmlSerializer`, the method needs to be `public`, i.e.

```cs
public bool ShouldSerializeConfiguration()
{
    return serializeConfig;
}
```

This isn't the case for some other scenarios, but `XmlSerializer` essentially works as an independently compiled assembly, so full visibility rules apply.